# cargo version: What doest the -nightly suffix mean?

Tags: rust

I've built a rust toolchain using someone else's repo, and it contains
a configure line I'm not familiar with: `--release-channel=nightly`

After I build and install the toolchain it reports its version as:

```
rustc 1.57.0-nightly (f1edd0429 2021-11-29)
```

while the standard off the shelf install of 1.57 reports its version as:

```
rustc 1.57.0 (f1edd0429 2021-11-29)
```

What does the `nightly` suffix mean in this version string?

Comment: It's the bleeding edge of rust. The latest bug fixes (not yet released to stable), experimental APIs and, occasionally, new bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Nightly is an unstable, unfinished, experimental version of Rust.

The name comes from the fact that literally every night a new "nightly" version is automatically released from whatever happens to be in the rust-lang repository at the time.

The nightly version allows use of Rust features that are still work in progress, special unstable features that are private to the compiler or the standard library, or even features that were failed experiments and will never be available in the stable releases of the Rust language.

Nightly versions may crash, may miscompile code, may stop working at any time. There is absolutely no warranty about them. Do not use them unless you specifically want to test the latest, unfinished Rust language features.

---

There's one case where users may hear about "nightly" features: when they use an outdated version of the compiler.

When an old Rust version sees language features "from the future", it may ask you to enable nightly features to use the code. This is misleading. You should upgrade Rust to the latest stable version instead of using nightly.